Konsole terminal
Why does not the Konsole terminal seem to be working in Ubuntu 22.04?
In 18.04 (and 16.04), it used to be a very convenient terminal.
In 22.04, it first did not allow any executable commands, saying
"permission denied", and I could not change the background color
or permanently change the font size. I do not remember whether
I did anything there, but now it even fails to provide the
command line, saying:
Warning: Could not start program '/usr/bin/' with arguments ''.
Warning: Child process set up failed: execve: Permission denied
Is it possible to make it work as in 18.04? If not, is there a
recommendable convenient terminal other than Terminal itself,
which changes its size only discretely.
Thanks.

Konsole works. You must've changed or replaced some major library. Did you change your python version? The errors you describe might indicate a missing or corrupt file system.Or a wrong library.

Thanks. The filesystem seems to work ok otherwise. Permissions were denied from the very beginning, and I could not find how to permanently change the font size or background color. How can I fix the library issue or redownload Konsole? Thanks.

See at: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/konsole/konsole/index.html

The errors I cited are apparently due to a wrong profile I accidentally created. When I switched to the "built-in", they disappeared and I do get the command line. But the issue of permissions remains, as also how to handle the parameters.  I want a white background instead of black and to be able to execute the commands. Say vi does not work. Thanks.

To vi with a file name, I get: bash: /usr/bin/vi: Permission denied. But the command is executable there. Thanks.

It seems that the "built-in" profile that was there is "Read-only", which probably explains the permissions issue. It seems like one has to work really hard to study how to make Konsole operationally convenient. This was not the case in 18.04. Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks.
